# [reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") not returning VersionString

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2012

I have the following powershell script that we run on many servers to retrieve the SQL VersionString:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | out-null
$srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" "."
$srv.VersionString
```

It works for all servers except one, which returns the a blank line.

Running just:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | out-null
New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" "."
```

Returns:

```
AuditLevel                  : 
BackupDirectory             : 
BrowserServiceAccount       : 
BrowserStartMode            : 
BuildClrVersionString       : 
BuildNumber                 : 
ClusterName                 : 
ClusterQuorumState          : 
ClusterQuorumType           : 
Collation                   : 
CollationID                 : 
ComparisonStyle             : 
ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS : 
DefaultFile                 : 
DefaultLog                  : 
Edition                     : 
ErrorLogPath                : 
FilestreamLevel             : 
FilestreamShareName         : 
HadrManagerStatus           : 
InstallDataDirectory        : 
InstallSharedDirectory      : 
InstanceName                : 
IsCaseSensitive             : 
IsClustered                 : 
IsFullTextInstalled         : 
IsHadrEnabled               : 
IsSingleUser                : 
Language                    : 
LoginMode                   : 
MailProfile                 : 
MasterDBLogPath             : 
MasterDBPath                : 
MaxPrecision                : 
NamedPipesEnabled           : 
NetName                     : 
NumberOfLogFiles            : 
OSVersion                   : 
PerfMonMode                 : 
PhysicalMemory              : 
PhysicalMemoryUsageInKB     : 
Platform                    : 
Processors                  : 
ProcessorUsage              : 
Product                     : 
ProductLevel                : 
ResourceLastUpdateDateTime  : 
ResourceVersionString       : 
RootDirectory               : 
ServerType                  : 
ServiceAccount              : 
ServiceInstanceId           : 
ServiceName                 : 
ServiceStartMode            : 
SqlCharSet                  : 
SqlCharSetName              : 
SqlDomainGroup              : 
SqlSortOrder                : 
SqlSortOrderName            : 
Status                      : 
TapeLoadWaitTime            : 
TcpEnabled                  : 
VersionMajor                : 
VersionMinor                : 
VersionString               : 
Name                        : SERVERDR
Version                     : 
EngineEdition               : 
ResourceVersion             : 
BuildClrVersion             : 
DefaultTextMode             : True
Configuration               : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Configuration
AffinityInfo                : 
ProxyAccount                : 
Mail                        : 
Databases                   : 
Endpoints                   : 
Languages                   : 
SystemMessages              : 
UserDefinedMessages         : 
Credentials                 : 
CryptographicProviders      : 
Logins                      : 
Roles                       : 
LinkedServers               : 
SystemDataTypes             : 
JobServer                   : 
ResourceGovernor            : 
ServiceMasterKey            : 
Settings                    : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Settings
Information                 : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Information
UserOptions                 : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.UserOptions
BackupDevices               : 
FullTextService             : 
ActiveDirectory             : 
Triggers                    : 
Audits                      : 
ServerAuditSpecifications   : 
AvailabilityGroups          : 
ConnectionContext           : Data Source=.;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Application Name="SQL Management"
Events                      : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ServerEvents
OleDbProviderSettings       : 
Urn                         : 
Properties                  : 
UserData                    : 
State                       : Existing
IsDesignMode                : False
DomainName                  : SMO
DomainInstanceName          :
```

So the question is, why is it not returning information about SQL that is installed on this server?

Server Details:
Windows 2008 R2
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64) 
Powershell Version 5.1

Comment: Looks like the account doesn't have permissions to connect to this instance so the information can't be retrieved.

Comment: How would I configure it to have permission?

Comment: It should be noted, that I am logged in as Administrator, which is a full admin, so im surprised it doesn't have permission to view this information.

Comment: Windows admin permissions do not automatically provide SQL Server permissions. You'll need to execute SQL query `CREATE LOGIN [YourServer\Administrator] FROM WINDOWS;` so the powershell script can connect.

Comment: Is there a way of receiving the VersionString without creating a Login?

Comment: Not using SMO. I think that information could be gleaned from the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, for SQL Server 2008, you need to load a secondary assembly aswell:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
#Need SmoExtended for smo.backup
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
```

At least, you need that when you want to do a SQL Server restore in SQL Server, so perhaps it is also needed for your purposes.

I found that info [here](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/06/01/how-to-restore-sql-server-databases-using-smo-and-powershell/)

I can't test this myself though..